# Can't fetch item from the Java DelayQueue

Tags: java, blockingqueue

I use the DelayQueue to store items. In some concurrent scenario, the consumer can't get any items. The code sample is listed below. Any tip can be helpful.

```
private BlockingQueue<Item> queue = new DelayQueue<>();

    producer 
    {
        if (!queue.contains(item)) {
            queue.offer(tiem);
        }
    }

    consumer implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                item = queue.take().getItem();
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: `queue.offer(tiem);` is that a typo?

Comment: Can you post a complete sample code to figure out?